# When do we have $B_Y\subset T(B_X)$ if and only if $\overline{B_Y}\subset T(\overline{B_X})$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, banach-spaces

Let $X$,$Y$ be normed spaces, $T:X\to Y$ be a bounded linear operator. Denote the open and closed unit balls by
$$
B_X:=\{ x\in X\ |\ \|x\|<1\} \\
\overline{B_X}:=\{ x\in X\ |\ \|x\|\le1\}
$$ 
and similarly for $B_Y,\overline{B_Y}$.

It is not hard to show that $\overline{B_Y}\subset T(\overline{B_X}) \implies B_Y\subset T(B_X)$. However the converse is false. Indeed, consider the counter example $X=l^1(\Bbb N), Y=\Bbb R$ and 
$$
T(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{nx_n}{n+1}.
$$

> How do we characterize the spaces $X,Y$ such that $B_Y\subset T(B_X) \implies \overline{B_Y}\subset T(\overline{B_X})$?

I ask the same question in MSE a few days ago but got no satisfactory answer. The only answer showed that reflexivity is sufficient but what I want is an "iff" statement. Here is the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2010382/when-do-we-have-b-y-subset-tb-x-if-and-only-if-overlineb-y-subset-t-ove) to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$X$ reflexive; $Y$ at least one dimensional.  This follows from James' characterization of reflexivity.  If $X$ is not reflexive there is a norm one linear functional on $X$ that does not achieve its norm.